# Context Menu not working in ANGULARJS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add context menu but value is not populating.

```
<div class="m-l">
    <a class="item-country text-orange" href="#/app/CountryIps/{{item.data['name']}}/cCode/{{item.data['country-code']}}" target="_blank">
            {{item['data']['name']}}
        </a>
    <a class="item-ip" href="#/app/showIps/{{item.data['name']}}/ip/{{item.data['Ip']}}" target="_blank"><span context-menu="whiteList"> {{item.data['Ip']}}</span> </a>
    <a href="" class="item-type text-orange"> {{item.data['type']}} </a>
    <a class="detail-icon" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="" ng-click="showModal(item)">
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.whiteList = [
    ['Add to white list', function($itemScope, $event, ip) {
        whiteList(ip);
    }]
];
```

Now when I add context from template I got undefined in `ip` in controller.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a onClick="window.location.href='your link'">
```

Comment: Issue is with context menu not with link.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by myself to checking values of the $itemscope.

```
$itemScope.$parent.item.data.Ip
```

To get the value of the IP from template to controllers.